# Get and use json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json file

```
{
 "arr": [
  {
    "text1": "first",
    "text2": "second",
  },
  {
    "text11": "first",
    "text22": "second",
  }
 ]
}
```

and I want get this object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../test.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.arr);
    }
});
```

and this are working.
But if I want assign a value to a variable, it doesn't work.

```
    success: function(data) {
        var arrTest = data.arr;
    }

    console.log(arrTest);
```

return arrTest is not defined

Comment: because you are accessing attTest outsite of success function

Comment: Your json is not valid.  Remove comma after "Second",

Comment: The problem is twofold: 1. `arrTest` is local to the function it's declared in and will be deleted when the function has completed. You read this variable outside that function, therefore it's undefined. 2. Even if you would declare it globally, `console.log()` accesses it before the **async** call has initialized `data`.